# Aquamacs banner for Latex got ugly — how to get the default back?

Tags: auctex, aquamacs

I was setting up Aquamacs as my LaTeX editor on a new laptop (been using it for 4 years on prior machine).

My one problem is that the beautiful header I was expecting:
[image: Nice Header]

Was replaced by this ugly mess: 
[image: Not so nice header]

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

I've tried:

- uninstalling and reinstalling Aquamacs
- direct copy-paste of the ~/.emacs file from my old install of Aquamacs

Comment: Same problem here. As far as I can tell, nothing changed. I didn't change machines; it just happened. Aquamacs executable and preferences files all have old dates.

Comment: Hi there!  You'll be happy to know I have no damn idea how to fix it and am resigned to having a screwed up interface.  My guess is that the ugly icons infiltrate your machine via miktex somehow...

Comment: I posted something to the emacs mailing last and will repost here should I hear anything. This really sucks. Beyond the icons, the display of superscripts and subscripts changed.